# Generating script for subset of the data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way I can use Generate and Publish Scripts to generate INSERTs for a subset of my data, e.g., requested > '2011-09-01' where requested is a field in my table?

Comment: Dunno but SSMS Tools Pack addin "Generate Insert Statements" allows you to set a filter

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the venerable sp_generate_inserts, which allows you to specify a filter condition using the @from parameter. The original version can be found at  http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt, although it's not without (minor) bugs, there might be a better version of this by now, although I haven't come across one.